# How to implement addable fields with Formik and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm trying to create an addable form like this photo with the help Formik :

[image]

But what is the best practice to implement this feature ?

In this case, name and price are textbox, but product categories are different with nested concept !

With this form, user can add a product to multi categories, user can add more fields and set new categories.

Due to the arrows, user must follow steps to set a category item in the last step !

Also user can delete no needed rows ...

I've searched into StackOverflow and Google, but I didn't find any suitable solution.

Thanks

Comment: How to find and fill drop-downs ? I must select drop downs with `document.getElementById` and then append childs ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`FieldArray`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray).

> `<FieldArray />` is a component that helps with common array/list manipulations. You pass it a name property with the path to the key within values that holds the relevant array.  will then give you access to array helper methods via render props. For convenience, calling these methods will trigger validation and also manage touched for you.

So you will need a initial value that is an array and another to tell what will be the name or the input you want when adding a new field.

If you look at the example in the docs, it's exactly what you need.

Comment: ok, I've read that link, but how can I manage drop-downs fill after changed prev step drop-down ? I should access to the next drop-down by ID and `document.getElementByID` or you have different method ? For example, if user changed the category, I should fill subcategory and because multi drop-downs it's not possible with single state or array index in FieldArrays

Comment: @Alex First, in react, in 99% of the cases you don't need and shouldn't use `document.getElementByID`. Second, you would need to show your code so I can understand better what you doing, I'm a little confuse.

Comment: that picture is the best description for the use case ... I need a trick to fill next drop downs, for example after change category fill sub category or on row 10 change the sub category I find and fill category items ... because it's unlimited rows

Comment: @Alex please show the code on how you are doing the drop downs, there is a million way of doing this. Please show what have you done so far

Comment: generally I think `<FieldArray />` lonely is not a suitable solution, because for edit I'll have a lot of problems to re render drop downs, fill those and handle onChange to fill next step drop downs ... really it's a painful challenge ! I've wrote approximately 600 line codes to implement this component and I don't think you understand that ;-)